# cant seem to access property from object

Tags: javascript, object

im struggling to understand why i cant access the properties that are created and returned in my function. if i console log the object itself. its successful, however, if i console log object.prop i get undefined. Here is my code

```
 function geocodeAddress(value) {
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // eslint-disable-line
            let data = {};
            geocoder.geocode({'address': value}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    data.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    data.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                }
            });
            return data;
        }

        const place = geocodeAddress('Leeds');

        console.log(place.longitude,place.latitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Property of `data` is set in `geocoder.geocode` function which is `async` function 
that's why It will always `return {}` 
You have several ways to handle aysnc work one of them is using `Promise`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
function geocodeAddress(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // eslint-disable-line
        let data = {};
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': value
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                data.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                data.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                resolve(data)
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        });

    })
}

let place = {};
geocodeAddress('Leeds').then(function(response) {
    place = response
    console.log(place.longitude, place.latitude);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

=> another option is using `async/await`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function